# Unity. "Stretching" of an object instantiated from prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to spawn obstacles on the road. To do so, I generate a road by spawning its parts, and each part itself spawns several obstacles in bounds of themselves. But some prefabs after being instantiated got strange "stretching" effects. I don't know how to explain it, so I recorded a small video [link](https://youtu.be/hk5_YqgFVCQ). Also, if I spawn that same object by "drag n drop" to the scene, this bug never appears.

This how I spawn obstacles:

```
            Vector3 size = GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size;
        Vector3 pos = new Vector3(Random.Range(-0.3f*size.x,0.3f*size.x), 30, Random.Range(-0.3f*size.z,0.3f*size.z));
        Debug.Log(pos + transform.position +"");

        GameObject newBottle = Instantiate(minus_prefabs[Random.Range(0, minus_prefabs.Length)], new Vector3(transform.position.x+pos.x,transform.position.y + pos.y,transform.position.z+pos.z), Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0));
        newBottle.transform.SetParent(transform);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the parent GameObject of the model has diffrent sizes on X, Y and Z. This results in some weird stretching. Try going in your prefab and set the scale of your main GameObject to `X:1 Y:1 Z:1` for example.

Also see: [https://www.unity3dtips.com/how-to-fix-objects-stretching-when-rotated/#:~:text=Cause%20of%20the%20object%20stretching,0.01%2C%200.002%2C%200.004%E2%80%9D](https://www.unity3dtips.com/how-to-fix-objects-stretching-when-rotated/#:%7E:text=Cause%20of%20the%20object%20stretching,0.01%2C%200.002%2C%200.004%E2%80%9D).

This also happens to me all the Time. Thankfully its easy to fix!

EDIT: When you instantiate the prefab, also make sure it has the same sizes on every axis.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, whenever possible, don't use any Scale other than 1,1,1 unless you need to and it should be on a leaf node of the hierarchy or prefab not a parent node. It will make things go much smoother. If you need to change the size of a mesh (because the noob modeler didn't know how to follow the life-sized scaling metrics in their modeling program, or you just want it smaller or larger), you can do that in the Import settings on the FBX.